# Changing icon for NSWindow title

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nsdocument

I am trying to change the proxy icon of a document window at runtime using

[[[self window] standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] setImage:img];

This is getting executed but the setting in info.plist is overriding this.

What is the right place to call this.

Answer (score 3):

In your `NSWindow` subclass override `setRepresentedURL` as follows:

```
- (void)setRepresentedURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    [super setRepresentedURL:url];
    NSImage* img = ...
    [[self standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] setImage:img];
}
```